# How to make array of filled contour graphs in R

Tags: r, plot, contour

I have a value that is a function of four independent real variables and want to do a 2D array of filled contour plots to help visualise its behaviour.

To simplify the problem, let's say the array is the one created by the following loop:

```
values.to.contour<-array(0,rep(5,4))
for (i1 in 1:5){
  for (i2 in 1:5){
    for (i3 in 1:5){
      for (i4 in 1:5){
        values.to.contour[i1,i2,i3,i4] <- sin(i1*2*pi/5) * sin(i2*2*pi*2/5) * sin(i3*2*pi*3/5) * sin(i4*2*pi*4/5)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can do non-filled contour plots with the following code:

```
    par(mfcol=c(5, 5), oma=rep(0.5,4), mai=rep(0.2,4) ) 
    for (i3 in 1:5){ # Loop 3
      for (i4 in 1:5){ # Loop 4
        #filled.contour(x=1:5 * 2 * pi * 3 / 5, y=1:5 * 2 * pi * 4 / 5, z=t(values.to.contour[ , , i3, i4]), levels = 0.25 * 0:8 -1, color.palette = rainbow)
        contour(x=1:5 * 2 * pi * 3 / 5, y=1:5 * 2 * pi * 4 / 5, z=t(values.to.contour[ , , i3, i4]), levels = 0.25 * 0:8 -1)
      }
    }
```

that produces a 5 x 5 array of contour plots, which is what I want.

But when I try to do it for filled.contour I only get the final plot, as full size, rather than an array of plots.

```
par(mfcol=c(5, 5), oma=rep(0.5,4), mai=rep(0.2,4) ) 
for (i3 in 1:5){ # Loop 3
  for (i4 in 1:5){ # Loop 4
    filled.contour(x=1:5 * 2 * pi * 3 / 5, y=1:5 * 2 * pi * 4 / 5, z=t(values.to.contour[ , , i3, i4]), levels = 0.25 * 0:8 -1, color.palette = rainbow) 
    #contour(x=1:5 * 2 * pi * 3 / 5, y=1:5 * 2 * pi * 4 / 5, z=t(values.to.contour[ , , i3, i4]), levels = 0.25 * 0:8 -1)
  }
}
```

Can anybody suggest a way of making the 25 filled.contour plots appear in a 5 x 5 array as the contour plots do?

Also, can anybody suggest how to make

- the colour guide appear only once, or at most five times (say at the
  RHS of each row of plots), rather than at the RHS of every one of the
  25 plots
- x axis tick labels appear only on the bottom row of plots
  and
- y axis tick labels appear only on the left hand column of plots?

thank you very much for any assistance

Andrew

Comment: I think this is what you want, but I'm having trouble working with your example multidimensional array for the z-values https://rdrr.io/cran/mosaic/man/panel.levelcontourplot.html

Comment: From the documentation: "filled.contour uses the layout function and so is restricted to a full page display."

Comment: @Hack-R thank you for your suggestion. I installed mosaic package and tried using panel.levelcontourplot, but kept getting the error "Error in contourLines .... : no proper 'z' matrix specified". I can't understand why it gives that error, as the matrix passes every test I tried on it.

Comment: Here's the code I inserted in place of the filled.contour call (sorry that I can't get it to format the code properly within this comment):                                  [code]    z=as.matrix(t(values.to.contour[ , , i3, i4]))
    print(dim(z))
    print(paste('is.matrix(z)=',is.matrix(z)))
    print(mode(z))
    print(class(z))
    print(paste('z fail condition=', !is.matrix(z) || nrow(z) <= 1 || ncol(z) <= 1) )
    panel.levelcontourplot(x=1:5, y=1:5, z=z, at = 0.25 * 0:8 - 1, col.regions = rainbow(7)) 
[/code]

Comment: If you could post an example of panel.levelcontourplot working on ANY data that would be great. The mosaic package documentation contains no examples, and I have been unable to find any on the internet.